# Cannot append float inside a IF loop ? How to overcome it?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a code which reads something like this

```
def IV_function(IVdata):     # IVdata is a dataframe
    for ...:
        if ..: 
            vmp = IVdata['iv_v'].iloc[max_idx]
            vmpaux.append(vmp)
    IVdata['vmp'] = vmpaux
    return IVdata
### Main code
df_s1 = IV_function(df_s1)  ### df_s1 is a dataframe
df_s2 = IV_function(df_s2)  ### df_s2 is a dataframe
```

Output:

```
df_s2 = explore_ivcurves(df_s2)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-59-3494dc1142b8>", line 1, in <module>
    df_s2 = explore_ivcurves(df_s2)

  File "<ipython-input-56-9ea07b888c4b>", line 23, in explore_ivcurves
    vmpaux.append(vmp)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Interestingly, this function ran successfully without any errors for another dataframe `df_s1`. The function gives error for second dataframe `df_s2`.

Comment: where are you defining vmpaux? What I am guessing is that you wanted that to be a list of float instead vmpaux is initialized as a float

Comment: @kkawabat it was not dependent on the function. So, I did not mention it to minimize the length of the post.

Comment: But that is what's causing the issue you are trying to append vmp to vmpaux but vmpaux is just a number. We need more information then what you are providing to help, can you give us what you are looping and the initialization of vmpaux?

Comment: You can't append a float *to another float*, because floats don't have an append operation -- and they couldn't be expected to anyhow; what would it do if they did? If you had a list, you could append *to that list*.

Comment: we need to know where vmpaux is defined or at least its value when you call it with .append() as mentioned by kkawabat

Comment: ...so, your `explore_ivcurves` is broken insofar as it's trying to append a float to another float, vs appending to something that can actually be appended to; or the way you're calling it is broken, giving it the wrong datatype. Either way, you aren't giving us a [mcve], so we can't reproduce the problem, much less fix it.

Comment: (Maybe your `df_s2` isn't actually a dataframe when `explore_ivcurves` is called? Without a reproducer, though, all we can offer is guesswork... which is why questions that would need a reproducer to be concrete rather than vague are disallowed here when lacking them).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your trying to use your float() as a list() somewhere. That's why you are seeing the `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'` error. It's telling you that `vmpaux` is a float.

You might also want to make sure that your variables exist with default values before you try to add them or when `IVdata['vmp'] = vmpaux` is called the vmp and vmpaux exist if the `if` is not used during the loop.

```
def IV_function(IVdata):     # IVdata is a dataframe
    vmpaux = []
    for ...:
        vmp = 0.0
        if ..: 
            vmp = IVdata['iv_v'].iloc[max_idx]
            vmpaux.append(vmp)
    IVdata['vmp'] = vmpaux
    return IVdata
### Main code
df_s1 = IV_function(df_s1)  ### df_s1 is a dataframe
df_s2 = IV_function(df_s2)  ### df_s2 is a dataframe
```